# lxml xpath RDF not working

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, rdf

I'm trying to extract the `/RDF/Description/id/text()` string, which should be `someid` below. What is the appropriate xpath to do extract this using python's lxml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
       - License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
       - file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. -->
    <RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
      <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
        <em:id>my-extension@mozilla</em:id>
        <em:version>initial</em:version>
        <em:type>2</em:type>
        <em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap>
        <em:unpack>false</em:unpack>

        <!-- Firefox -->
        <em:targetApplication>
            <Description>
                <em:id>{someid}</em:id>
                <em:minVersion>7.0</em:minVersion>
                <em:maxVersion>27.0</em:maxVersion>
            </Description>
        </em:targetApplication>

        <!-- Front End MetaData -->
        <!-- must provide default non-localized because It's used as a default on AMO. It's used as a default by the add-on manager, with the possibility of other locales overriding it. Failure to provide a non-localized name will lead to failed upload on AMO. -->
        <em:name>l10n</em:name>
        <em:description>ff-addon-demo: Shows how to localize restartless add-ons.</em:description>
        <em:creator>Noitidart</em:creator>
        <!-- start localizing -->
        <em:localized>
            <Description>
                <em:locale>en-GB</em:locale>
                <em:name>l10n :: en-GB</em:name>
                <em:description>en-GB :: ff-addon-demo: Shows how to localize restartless add-ons. </em:description>
                <em:creator>en-GB :: Noitidart</em:creator>
            </Description>
        </em:localized>
        <em:localized>
            <Description>
                <em:locale>en-US</em:locale>
                <em:name>l10n :: en-US</em:name>
                <em:description>en-US :: ff-addon-demo: Shows how to localize restartless add-ons. </em:description>
                <em:creator>en-US :: Noitidart</em:creator>
            </Description>
        </em:localized>
      </Description>
    </RDF>
```

I've actually tried all these: `"*/*[4]" , "*/*[4]" , "*/*" , "@my:*" , "em:*" , "my:*" , "@*" , "//id" , "//em:id" , "//em" , "//*[text()='USA']" , "{http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#}:localized" , "*/*" , "//tag:RDF" , "//*RDF" , "/RDF/Description/em:targetApplication" , "*/localized" , "*/*localized" , "*/*" , "*/*" , "*/*" , "*/*" , "*/*" , "*/*" , "*/http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#" , "*/RDF" , "*/*" , "/RDF" , "//RDF" , "/RDF", ".//Description" , "//?xml" , "//about" , "//em" , "//Description" , "/RDF" , "*/*" , "*/Description" , "*/Descriptoin" , "*" , "./?xml" , "?xml" , "//?xml" , "//http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}RDF" , "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}RDF" , "//version" , "//xml" , "//" , "//RDF" , "./version" , "version" , "xml" , "/RDF/Description/*"  , "/RDF/Description"`, wasting a lot time fruitlessly.

Edit: After the solution below, I found this good reference document for this common issue
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950779.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible way; see how the XPath corresponds to the XML structure, and how to reference XML element in namespace using XPath :

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """your xml as posted in question here"""
root = etree.fromstring(xml)
nsmap = {'d': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#',
         'em': 'http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#'}
result = root.xpath("/d:RDF/d:Description/em:targetApplication/d:Description/em:id/text()",
                    namespaces=nsmap)
print(result)
```

**output :**

```
['{someid}']
```

Comment: I couldn't really find a good reference for xpath, and it seems lxml only implements a subset of the specification. I searched for xml namespace, for RDF, etc, I just think there's a documentation failure somewhere and I didn't want to waste too much time on this extremely simple task.

Comment: @erjoalgo `lxml` has [*full support* of XPath version 1.0](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html). You can read [W3School's](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) for starter, and consult the [official XPath 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) for complete details